# Program hangs at a particular line in a function without a signal from operating system

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qdockwidget

I am making a library management software in qt. I have a LogWindow class in which displays the log (basically " 'x' issued book 'y' on date 'abc' "). I added a QDockWidget to filter the results like say, the user only wants to see today's activity or say the user wants to see who all issued book 'x' till date.

The problem is the program suddenly stops executing.

In my LogWindow constructor I call createDock function which is a private function:

```
void LogWindow :: createDock()
{
    //initialize main layout of dock
    layout = new QVBoxLayout;

//initialize dock
dock = new QDockWidget("Filters", this);
dock->setAllowedAreas(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea | Qt::RightDockWidgetArea);
dock->setWindowTitle("Filters");
dock->setFeatures(QDockWidget::DockWidgetFloatable | QDockWidget::DockWidgetMovable);

//make group boxes
filters = new QWidget(this);

createHistory();
createIssuedBy();
createBookIssued();

filters->setLayout(layout);
dock->setWidget(filters);

this->addDockWidget(Qt::RightDockWidgetArea, dock);
dock->show();
}
```

Don't know why but the program works till the second last line but the last line is not executed. I found this by setting breakpoint on each line of the function.

```
void LogWindow::createBookIssued()
{
    //book issued group box
    bookIssued = new QGroupBox("Book Issued");

book = new QLineEdit;
QHBoxLayout *bookIssuedLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
bookIssuedLayout->addWidget(bookIssued);
bookIssued->setLayout(bookIssuedLayout);

layout->addWidget(bookIssued);
}
```

I dont receive any signal from the Operating system but the program stops responding to any event. Neither is the LogWindow shown.

So, I commented the call to 'createBookIssued()' function and everything works fine. Dock works, the LogWindow is shown, the program works just as expected

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the third last line of createBookIssued() I was adding bookIssued (group box) to the layout and then setting the layout to the same bookIssued. Replaced third last line with:

```
bookIssuedLayout->addWidget(book);
```

The program now works as expected